# コマンドプロンプトでvue serveを実行できない：Please run npm i -g @vue/cli-service-global and try again

Tags: vue.js

#### 解決したいこと

掌田津耶乃さん著のVue.JS 3 超入門という本を学習しているのですが、序盤でつまずいています。
コマンドプロンプトでvue serveを実行しようとしているのですが、うまくいきません。

#### 発生している問題・エラー

Vue CLIはダウンロードインストール済みなのですが、下記スクショの下から2行目にある通り、Please run npm i -g @vue/cli-service-global and try againという表示が出てしまい、 `vue serve` することが出来ません。本の通りに進めているはずなのですが、なぜ実行できないのでしょうか？
どなたかわかる方教えていただきたいです。

[image: スクリーンショット 2021-10-10 222857.png]

Comment: その書籍の Kindle 版の試し読みを参照してみたのですが、40ページに「Vue cli-service-global のインストール」という項目があります。そこには `npm install -g @vue/cli-service-global`を実行するようにと書かれています。

Comment: 先ほど回答の通りに実行してみたところ、無事にvue serveをすることができました。迅速な回答ありがとうございます。metropolisさん本当に感謝しております。

Comment: taipi1576 さん> 横から失礼します。解決されたようでよかったです。もしよろしければ、解決された方法を[回答として投稿](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)し、この質問を解決済みにしていただけませんか？

Answer (score 0):

その書籍の Kindle 版の試し読みを参照してみたのですが、40ページに「Vue cli-service-global のインストール」という項目があります。そこには npm install -g @vue/cli-service-globalを実行するようにと書かれています。

いただいたコメントの通りにコマンドを実行した結果、vue serveをすることができました。metropolisさんありがとうございます。